# Mutually recursive definition in OCaml

Tags: binding, ocaml

I know that OCaml provide the `let rec ... and ...` for definition of mutually recursive function. Why I can't use that expression for define mutually recursive value?

In particular, why I can't do something like `let rec x=3 and y=x+5 in x` but I can do `let rec x=3 and y=[x;4] in y`?

For the first case, I've try to give me an answer and I think that is a binding "problem", since the binding of the values should be simultaneous, so y can't know the value of x so I can't add it to the value of the constant 5. 
It is true?

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your definitions are mutually recursive. You could just as well write them like this:

```
let x = 3 in
let y = x + 5 in
x
```

and

```
let x = 3 in
let y = [x; 4] in
y
```

Mutually recursive definitions would look like this:

```
let rec x = y + 3
and y = x + 5 in
x
```

and

```
let rec x = 3 :: y
and y = 4:: x in
x
```

In the second piece of code `x` is a cyclic list that contains a 3 followed by a 4 and then loops back to the beginning. However the first piece of code doesn't make any sense. How can `x` equal `y + 3` when `y` equals `x + 5`? It can't and therefore recursive values can only be defined using constructors of variant types (because that's the only case where a recursive value would not lead to infinite recursion).

So since recursive values can't be defined without constructors and the `let rec ... and` syntax is not necessary when the value you're trying to define is not recursive, the syntax simply can not be used with anything but constructor applications.

Comment: Ok, effectively my examples aren't really mutually defined. So, if I've understood what you saying, my first example not work because integer cannot be defined with `let rec... and ...` expression because they aren't variant.

Comment: It is not actually the fact that `x` is an integer that is the problem, it is the fact that `+` is a function, and so is not "statically constructive". For a full description of the restrictions on recursive values see [Section 7.3](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/extn.html#sec213) of the manual.

Comment: @LeoWhite You're right - my bad. It should be fixed now.